# Different Edm.DateTime formatting behavior Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: sapui5

In one XML view I have 4 tables, bound to 4 different entity sets.
For the date fields, in all 4 tables I'm using the custom formatter below.
For 2 tables the date fields come up empty in Firefox, but show up correctly in Chrome. There is no error in the console. All bindings of the date columns in all 4 tables are using the exact same code apart from the property names.
All fields are of type Edm.DateTime.

Date column binding:

```
<m:Text text="{path:'Begda', formatter:'com.pj.customapp.util.Formatter.formatDate'}"/>
```

Formatter function:

```
formatDate: function(date) {
        if (date !== null && typeof date.getMonth === 'function' ) { 
            if (date.getYear() === 0){
                return "";
            }

            return date.toLocaleDateString();
        }
        return "";
    },
```

Comment: Found the problem: cached $metadata in Firefox! 
Can someone explain why SHIFT+reload or CTRL+SHIFT+R does not GET a new $metadata, but still uses the cached one?
I had to disable cache in the developer tools options and then reload...

Comment: Is metadata Caching disabled in your system? Try disabling it via transaction `SPRO` and then *SAP Netweaver > SAP Gateway > OData Channel > Administration > Cache Settings > Metadata > Activate/Deactivate Cache*

Comment: @Marc Thanks, I didn't know this was possible. It's recommended to only turn this off on the development system or is there a good reason to turn this off on prod too?

Comment: Metadata won't change that often on a prod system. You can manually clear the cache in transaction `/IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP` on the hub system and `/IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP` on the backend system after you've imported changes.